# Duplicating epoll file descriptor

Tags: c, linux, file-descriptor, epoll, dup

Is there a way to duplicate a file descriptor created using `epoll_create`, in such a way that the copy can be modified (adding/removing watched file descriptors using `epoll_ctl`) independently.

E.g. I create an epoll file descriptor `A` which waits for events on the files `P` and `Q`. The I copy it to epoll file descriptor `B`, and make `B` also waits for events on file `R`. Calling `epoll_wait(A)` will still only wait for `P` and `Q`.

Is this the behavior when calling `dup` on `A`, or is it needed to recreate the epoll file descriptor using `epoll_create` and `epoll_ctl`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit confusing.

When you open a new file, two entities are created. One if the file handle in the kernel. The other is a file descriptor, a number referencing that file handle.

While I don't know for sure what will happen with an epoll fd, I am assuming it is the same as with any other duplicate fds, and that is that they are the same file handle.

For a hint of that, this excerpt from the `epoll(2)` man page might help:

> **Q6**  Will closing a file descriptor cause it to be removed from all epoll sets automatically?
>
> **A6**  Yes, but be aware of the following point.  A file descriptor is a reference to an open file description (see `open(2)`). 
>   Whenever a descriptor is duplicated via `dup(2)`,
>              `dup2(2)`, `fcntl(2)` `F_DUPFD`, or `fork(2)`, a new file descriptor referring to the same open file description is created.  An
>   open file description continues to exist until
>              all  file descriptors referring to it have been closed.  A file descriptor is removed from an epoll set only after all the file
>   descriptors referring to the underlying
>              open file description have been closed (or before if the descriptor is explicitly removed using `epoll_ctl(2)`  `EPOLL_CTL_DEL`).
>   This  means  that  even  after  a  file
>              descriptor  that  is  part  of an epoll set has been closed, events may be reported for that file descriptor if other file
>   descriptors referring to the same underlying
>              file description remain open.

So, while I have not checked it myself, I am guessing that `dup` will not allow you to duplicate the epoll's filter list in any way. Both `fd`s will reference the same file handle. Any filter change done to one will be reflected in the other.

Unfortunately, since there is no API that I'm aware of to query `epoll`'s filter list, that means you have no way to do what you want, short of keeping track from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

You can operate the duplicate epfd on different underlying file struct(or the same file struct with different fd) independently.